# UTC [38] ERROR: could not obtain lock on row in relation "ir_cron" (after Fetchmail Service action)

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

I have Odoo 13 comunity edition running locally in docker container (OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). I  have connected Incoming Mail Server (imap.gmail.com). Now every time after scheduled action "Mail: Fetchmail Service" this error apearing:

```
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:10:29,290 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Starting job `Mail: Fetchmail Service`. 
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:10:29,318 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on imap server test_gmail_in_IMAP 
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:10:30,880 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: Fetched 0 email(s) on imap server test_gmail_in_IMAP; 0 succeeded, 0 failed. 
db_1   | 2020-02-07 07:10:31.076 UTC [37] ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "ir_cron"
db_1   | 2020-02-07 07:10:31.076 UTC [37] STATEMENT:  SELECT *
db_1   |                                               FROM ir_cron
db_1   |                                               WHERE numbercall != 0
db_1   |                                                  AND active
db_1   |                                                  AND nextcall <= (now() at time zone 'UTC')
db_1   |                                                  AND id=8
db_1   |                                               FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
db_1   | 2020-02-07 07:10:31.207 UTC [38] ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "ir_cron"
db_1   | 2020-02-07 07:10:31.207 UTC [38] STATEMENT:  SELECT id FROM "ir_cron" WHERE id IN (8) FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:10:31,312 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Job `Mail: Fetchmail Service` done.
```

When I run this action manually there is no errors:

```
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:36:59,253 1 INFO odoo_call_center werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2020 07:36:59] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/ir.attachment/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 - 5 0.002 0.004
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:36:59,274 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on imap server test_gmail_in_IMAP 
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:37:00,375 1 INFO odoo_call_center odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: Fetched 0 email(s) on imap server test_gmail_in_IMAP; 0 succeeded, 0 failed. 
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:37:00,755 1 INFO odoo_call_center werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2020 07:37:00] "POST /web/dataset/call_button HTTP/1.1" 200 - 33 0.026 1.473
web_1  | 2020-02-07 07:37:00,838 1 INFO odoo_call_center werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2020 07:37:00] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/ir.cron/read HTTP/1.1" 200 - 60 0.023 0.020
```

Mail servis is working actually: I can recive and send emails. I set the `interval_number` to 10 minutes so it not too smal. Setting `max_cron_threads = 1` insted of `max_cron_threads = 2` also have no effect.

I'm new in working with Odoo and in programming at whole. I would be glad to receive advice.

Comment: You could check if the cron job executions do not overlap.